# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured import Counter from './components/counter.jsx'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Im trying to setup a new js/typescript environment to practice web dev while using react, yarn, and webpack but I keep getting this error when trying to get it set up. My current configs look like this. I am new to all of this so if you see anything I should change then please let me know.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['react'],
            },
          },
        ],

        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function () {
                return [require('precss'), require('autoprefixer')]
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'saas-loader',
          },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import Counter from './components/counter.jsx'

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "trend-dot-com",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "TBA",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --progress"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `import Counter from './components/counter'` without the file ending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first look everything looked Ok. But the problem seems to be in your webpack.config file.

Try below

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: 
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets:["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react" ]
            },
          },
      },
    {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function () {
                return [require('precss'), require('autoprefixer')]
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'saas-loader',
          },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
}
```

Also after changing this there is a css-loader error which is not installed , so you can install and add that to your package.json. But since you already have Sass packages may be you want to refer the bootstrap sass version in your index.js - upto you. Hope this helps!.

Comment: The main file you have for the app is index.js and it contains component which need transpiling, so thought above should be needed.

Comment: This is exactly the same as `test: /\.jsx?$/,` they already have.

Comment: @GuyIncognito : You are right, it will evaluate to the same result. My bad - deleting the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer after a bit of troubleshooting.